# Cakephp saveAll continuously giving Array to string conversion error

Tags: cakephp-2.0, model-associations

I am developing an Application using 2 models, Users and profiles.
when I am trying to editing both models at a time, I am getting continuously this error
    **Array to string conversion [CORE\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php, line 1006]**
my `$this->request->data` array is in

```
array(
    'User' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'id' => '6',
        'first_name' => 'some',
        'middle_name' => 'kjkj',
        'last_name' => 'one',
        'username' => 'kadjssa',
        'group_id' => '5',
        'mobile_no' => '7867868'
    ),
    'Profile' => array(
        'skype' => 'shrinet'
    )
)
```

and my User controller edit function contain

```
public function editClient($id = null) {
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    debug($this->request->data);
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {

        $this->request->data['User']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->User('id');
        $this->request->data['Profile']['user_id'] = $id;

        debug($this->request->data);
        print_r (debug($this->User->invalidFields()));
        if ($this->User->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
    }
    $groups = $this->User->Group->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('groups'));
}
```

in debugging its giving

```
SQL Query: INSERT INTO `mvs`.`users` (`id`, `first_name`, `middle_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `password`, `group_id`, `mobile_no`, `user_id`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES (Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, '2013-07-05 00:07:13', '2013-07-05 00:07:13')
```

Please help me... thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't `$this->request->data['User']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->User('id');` be just `$this->request->data['User']['id'] = $this->Auth->User('id');`?? Are you sure the `saveAll` function is the one giving you trouble? The same happens changing that function for `saveAssociated`?

Comment: yes, I am sure this error caused by savaAll(), because saveAssiciated() is working fine....

Comment: What's the association between user and profile? belongsTo and hasOne?

Comment: user hasOne profile and
profile belongsTo user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank god,
  I found resolution......
just use `$this->User->saveAll($this->request->data, array('atomic' => false, 'deep' => true));` instead of `$this->User->saveAll($this->request->data);` because

> Be careful when checking saveAssociated calls with atomic option set to false. It returns an array instead of boolean
>   ch http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array

Answer (score 0):

The docs recommend to use `saveAssociated` or `saveMany` depending on the case

> This function receives the same options as the former two, and is generally a backwards compatible function. It is recommended using either saveMany or saveAssociated depending on the case

So the first choice is to change that `saveAll` to `saveAssociated`, since I think there's just *one* user and *one* profile.

All [saveAll](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/source-class-Model.html#1868-1909) does is to call `Set::numeric(array_keys($data))`, and if that is `true,` calls `saveMany`, otherwise `saveAssociated`. The problem probably is in that `Set::numeric` comparison. If you want to get to the bottom of that, do a debug of

```
Set::numeric(array_keys($this->request->data));
```

If that gives you `true`, it must consider your array to be numerically indexed. Then you'll need to start debugging why is considered that way, check the [Set::numeric](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/source-class-Set.html#204-231) function, where does the bad check, and change it or report it as a bug.

I think that trying to debug that is more troublesome than to change `saveAll` to `saveAssociated`, though, since you commented that the last gives you no problem.

Comment: I tried to debug `debug(Set::numeric(array_keys($this->request->data)));` but it giving me false;